# Integral of trigonometric function with parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I need to solve the integral $$\int \frac{dx}{1+a\cos x}$$ for $a\>>0$

I tried to use the substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ but unfortunately it doesn't seems to work here. after substitude all the trigo identities I got:

$\int \frac{dx}{1+acosx} = \int \frac{2dt}{1+t^2+a(1-t^2)}$

from here I am not sure how to procced

I would like for an explanation about this problem because I think it has a big lesson I can make from it.

Comment: It should work, please share your effort.

Comment: I added the result I got to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{1+acosx} = \int \frac{2dt}{1+t^2+a(1-t^2)}$$
$$I = \int \frac{2dt}{t^2(1-a)+a+1}$$
For $ a\ne 1$ we have ( otherwise $I=\int dt$):
$$I = \dfrac 2 {1-a}\int \frac{dt}{t^2+c}$$
Where $c=\dfrac {1+a}{1-a}$
Now it depends if $c > 0$ or $c<0$. If $c>0$ use the arctan function. For $c=0$ it's easy to integrate.For $c<0$ you can decompose the fraction and use the log function. For $a=1$ the integral is simple: $I=\int dt$.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from where you left,

$$\int \frac{2dt}{1+t^2+a(1-t^2)}$$
$$=2\int \frac{dt}{\left(\sqrt{(1-a)}t\right)^2+ (\sqrt{a+1})^2}$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-a}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{t\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right)+C$$