# Integral $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+t\cos x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

I figured out to use substitution $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ and arrived at integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2}{1+u^2+t(1-u^2)}du$  but am stuck here. Appreciate it if someone can drop some hint on how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: Now go from $u$ to $s$ via $$
u=\sqrt {\frac{{1 + t}}{{1 - t}}} s,
$$ with $t\neq 1$.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657045/integral-of-trigonometric-function-with-parameter

Comment: Presumably, $t<1$ to avoid poles. Then the denominator is proportional to $\frac{1-t}{1+t}u^2+1$ which reminds an $\arctan$. Rescale the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to add the condition that $\lvert t\rvert<1$, otherwise the integral does not converge. Note that if $\lvert t\rvert<1$, then $1+t\cos x\neq0,$ so there is no issue of possibly having an improper integral.

We continue from what you found:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\frac2{1+t+(1-t)u^2}\mathop{du}&=\frac{2}{1+t}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}u\right)^2}\mathop{du}\\
&=\frac{2}{1+t}\left.\left[\sqrt{\frac{1+t}{1-t}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}u\right)\right]\right|_0^\infty\\
&=\frac2{1+t}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{1-t}\cdot\left(\frac\pi2\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
\end{align*}